# Returning NULL pointer

Tags: c

I have function that deallocates struct:

```
typedef struct matrix_t {
  int r; // num of rows
  int c; // num of cols
  int *values;
} matrix_t;
```

function that does that is:

```
void deallocate_matrix(matrix_t **ptr) {
  if (ptr != NULL && *ptr != NULL) {
    free((*ptr)->values);
    (*ptr)->values = NULL;
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
  }
}
```

Then my main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  matrix_t *M[4] = {NULL};
  char op[2] = {0};
  int op_ret[2] = {0};
  M[0] = matrix_input();
  scanf(" %c", &op[0]);
  M[1] = matrix_input();
  M[2] = calc(M[0], M[1],op[0]);
  matrix_print(M[2]);
  deallocate_matrix((matrix_t **)&M[1]);
  assert(M[1] == NULL); //this looks ok, M[1] is NULL
  return 0;
}
```

But if I omit `deallocate_matrix((matrix_t **)&M[1]);` and deallocate with function *calc* like this:

```
matrix_t *calc(matrix_t *A, matrix_t *B, char op) {
  matrix_t *M = NULL;
  //some code to compute M
  deallocate_matrix((matrix_t **)&A);
  deallocate_matrix((matrix_t **)&B);
  return M;
}
```

the assertion M[1]==NULL would fail, so I am clearly doing something wrong in the calc function, but I am not sure what.

Comment: We need to see the code for `matrix_input`. And, the actual code for: `//some code to compute M`. Don't cast the arguments passed to `deallocate_matrix`. If you've done things correctly, you shouldn't have to. And, the cast may just be covering up bugs in the calling sequence. Also, there's little need to have `deallocate_matrix` use a double star pointer. It adds needless complexity. Try: `M[1] = deallocate_matrix(M[1]);` where you use: `matrix_t *deallocate_matrix(matrix_t *mtx) { ... return NULL; }` It achieves the same effect but is simpler.

Comment: deallocate_matrix takes the address of a pointer, so that it can change the pointer to point to NULL.  But calc doesn't take the address of a pointer, so main will never know that those pointers now point to NULL.  If you really need that change calc to `matrix_t *calc(matrix_t **A, matrix_t **B, char op)` but it just complicates everything.  Making code simpler is always better if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. The `assert` is wrong. Get rid of it and you won't have an issue. You have freed the matrix.

What's happening is that `calc` takes `A` and `B` by value. So it can't change the value of `A` or `B` in the caller. So they won't be `NULL` after the call.

```
  M[2] = calc(M[0], M[1],op[0]);
```

Here, we pass the *values* of `M[0]` and `M[1]` to `calc`. So `calc` can't change the value of `M[0]` or `M[1]` because it doesn't get a pointer to them. That's fine. There no reason it should.

Please just get out of the habit of senselessly setting pointers to `NULL` when you deallocate what they point to. It causes lots of pain the more complex your code gets.

You see the way `free` works, right? Your functions should work the same way for sanity, so:

```
void deallocate_matrix(matrix_t *ptr) {
  if (ptr != NULL) {
    free(ptr->values);
    free(ptr);
  }
}
```

Simple and easy to use.

Comment: Your answer makes it clear why my approach doesn't work. Thanks for that. The reason I set the pointers to NULL is that I was under impression it was good practice to do so (and also i was to do as at my course at school). I guess academia and real world differ :).I put the assert there just to test if my M[1] is null, I wouldn't leave it in actual code. I thought having pointer to point to NULL is useful in situation when I am trying to deallocate using my function as it test if the pointer is null and it wouldn't attempt to free it again.

Comment: In any case, i accept your answer. I need to work on understanding pointers better.Thank you

Comment: @cgnx It's very bad practice and it is a mystery to me why it is taught. You can't rely on it because there may be pointers to the same object in more than one place and there's absolutely no point in setting a member of a structure to a value right before you free that structure. (And look how much more complicated it makes your program and how it makes you deal with pointers to pointers and other totally needless complexity.)

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, now that you write it, setting member of structure to null sounds indeed stupid. But generally setting pointers to NULL is good practice right?

Comment: @cgnx No, it's not. Unless you are specifically going to test them in the code, it's a terrible practice. Look at how much more complex it makes your code, requiring an extra level of pointer indirection. And you can't rely on it in general because you may have pointers to the same object in more than one place. If it was sensible, `free` would do it.